# Using CSS properties in CSS selectors?

Tags: css

**Context**: I have three spans, A B C D (in that order). Based off of what is put in a form next to these spans, I turn the visibility off or on of these spans.

There's a line break in A and C that makes the display something like this :

```
A
B C
D
```

But if I hide C this ends up being :

```
A
B D
```

because the line break is not displayed.

What I'd like to do is add some other element  (C') that would display if B is displayed and C isn't.  So that , if C isn't there, I can still get the line break:

```
A
B (C')
D
```

I'm pretty sure this is possible by using a combination of class-based CSS switching and the `:after` pseudo-selector, but I'd rather like to avoid having to go in and modify the Javascript to change from the current `display:show/none` mechanisms. So my question ends up being :

Is it possible to 'inspect' currently set styles (such as 'display') in CSS rules ? I'd like to be able to do something similar to the attribute mechanism where I can do :

```
A[display='show']~B[display='none']:after { 
    content : '\a';
}
```

But just looking at the selectors I don't see how I could accomplish this without declaring new classes.

Comment: Can't you just put the break outside of the element? Therefore if `display:none;`, then it will still be there... idk, just trying to think outside of the box.

Comment: Why not use <div>'s and keep B and C spans but put them in a div too?

Comment: @JoshC that's a good suggestion, better than my suggestion unless there is some reason that a break isn't allowed "outside the box." Why don't you post that as an answer just in case? P.S. your use of words "outside the box" made me laugh because it is very good fit for putting the line break literally "outside the box."

Answer (score 2):

Looking at every case that you want, there is always a line break before element D. So why not begin element D with a line break instead of ending C with a line break? Then you would have either

```
A
B C
D
```

or

```
A
B
D
```

and never

```
A
B D
```

Note: In writing my answer, I assumed there was some reason that it is not allowed to do the obvious thing and just separate C and D with a line break that wasn't contained in either of them. If you are allowed to do that, then I hope that Josh will post his suggestion as an answer and receive votes for it.

Update: If you want to make the A and C always be broken onto separate lines from the B/C combination, then you can use `display: list-item` which seems very appropriate for making a span behave like a one-line item:

http://jsfiddle.net/gDYs6/1/

Comment: There's also the case where there's just D, in which I don't want the line break at all. But maybe I can just deal with it, it is a much easier solution

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if your layout will allow for it, but if you can float the elements to the left, you can use `clear: left;` on B and D, so that if C dissappears, D will still appear on a new line. Check the fiddle here and try removing C and run it again:

http://jsfiddle.net/gj6sn/

Edit: Forgot to mention, you will need to add a clearfix to the parent element, otherwise it will have 0 height. Updated jsfiddle and also read more here:

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/

Comment: 1+ I like this.. although, as you stated, it may not work in the layout.

Comment: `clear: left` on inline `span`s doesn't do anything without the additional `float: left` which will remove them from normal flow. It seems a little drastic. If you want to make the A and D spans display only on individual lines with CSS, then you could do this http://jsfiddle.net/gDYs6/ `.a, .d { display: list-item }`

Comment: Well it doesn't remove them from the normal flow, it's fairly standard to float elements for positioning blocks these days. One thing I forgot to mention is he'll need to add a clearfix so the parent element will have a height

Comment: To make clear: if you add elements after the spans, they will still be pushed down below the spans.

Comment: @Rich I wasn't criticizing your answer by saying that floats take elements out of the flow, I was just pointing out a fact to be considered. Taking an element out of the flow is what floating does. http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html "In the float model, a box is first laid out according to the normal flow, then taken out of the flow..."

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is jquery -

```
$("#dom_element").css("display")
```

will return you the current display style of whatever you reference. There's a way to do it in flat js but jquery is easy - what you want to do here is iterate through the A B C D matched class elements until you get to the one you want.

http://api.jquery.com/css/